# Why am I getting the error message in Xcode "unrecognized selector sent to class" in my Swift iOS app project?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple Instagram clone project that I am following along in a Udemy course with a LogInController class and a Registration class but when I run the app in an iOS 16.2 simulator using Xcode 14.2 with macOS Monterey 12.6.5 I get the following error message;

```
Thread 1: "+[InstagramFirestoreTutorial.LoginController presentRegistrationController]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10b086788"
```

when I click on "Don't have an account? Sign Up" at the bottom of the Log In screen, the LoginController calls an objective-C function to service the button tap and fails to instantiate the RegistrationController on line 118;

```
    @objc func presentRegistrationController() {
        let registrationController = RegistrationController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(registrationController, animated: true)
    }
```

Here is the LoginController class code;

```
//
//  LoginController.swift
//  InstagramFirestoreTutorial
//
//  Created by *** on 27/02/2023.
//

import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Class Properties
    
    private let iconImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Instagram_logo_white")!)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()
    
    private let emailTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let textField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email")
        textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        return textField
    }()
    
    private let passwordTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let textField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Password")
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return textField
    }()
        
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, passwordTextField, logInButton, passwordRetrievalButton])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private let logInButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "logInButton")
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        button.setHeight(50.0)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
        
    private let inviteRegistrationButton: UIButton = {
       
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setAttributedTitle(withQuestion: "Don't have an account?", andAction: "Sign Up")
        button.addTarget(LoginController.self, action: #selector(presentRegistrationController), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    private let passwordRetrievalButton: UIButton = {
       
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setAttributedTitle(withQuestion: "Forgotten your password?", andAction: "Get help logging in")
        return button
    }()

    // MARK: - Class Lifecycle Methods
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configureUI()
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Class Supplementary Methods
    
    private func configureUI() {
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        
        configureGradientLayer()
        
        configureSubviews()
    }
    
    private func configureSubviews() {
        
        view.addSubview(iconImageView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iconImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80.0),
            iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120.0),
            iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 32.0)
        ])
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -32.0)
        ])
        
        view.addSubview(inviteRegistrationButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            inviteRegistrationButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            inviteRegistrationButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    // MARK: - Button Action Selector Functions
    
    @objc func presentRegistrationController() {
        let registrationController = RegistrationController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(registrationController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And here is the RegistrationController class code;

```
//
//  RegistrationController.swift
//  InstagramFirestoreTutorial
//
//  Created by **** on 27/02/2023.
//

import UIKit

class RegistrationController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Class Properties
    
    private let profilePhotoButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus_photo"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    private let emailTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let textField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Email")
        textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
        return textField
    }()
    
    private let passwordTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let textField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Password")
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        return textField
    }()

    private let fullnameTextField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Fullname")
    
    private let usernameTextField = CustomTextField(placeholder: "Username")
    
    private let signUpButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "signUpButton")
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        button.setHeight(50.0)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    
    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, passwordTextField, fullnameTextField, usernameTextField, signUpButton])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()
    
    private let inviteToLogInButton: UIButton = {
       
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setAttributedTitle(withQuestion: "Already have an account?", andAction: "Log In")
        button.addTarget(RegistrationController.self, action: #selector(presentLogInController), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    

    
    // MARK: - Class Lifecycle Methods
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
            configureUI()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Class Supplementary Methods
    
    private func configureUI() {
        
        configureGradientLayer()
        
        addUISubviews()
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        
    }
    
    private func addUISubviews() {
        
        view.addSubview(profilePhotoButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profilePhotoButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            profilePhotoButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            profilePhotoButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140.0),
            profilePhotoButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140.0)
        ])
        
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePhotoButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -32.0)
        ])
        
        view.addSubview(inviteToLogInButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            inviteToLogInButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            inviteToLogInButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func presentLogInController() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the Log In screen.

[image: Log In Screen]

I have noticed that when I replace LogInController.self with self in the button's addTarget method the app works although I do get a warning in Xcode;

[image: Xcode warning]

Comment: @Rob Thanks I have used 'self' and made the button a lazy var and that works now with no warnings.

Comment: This seems like a specific question where a custom answer is appropriate rather than closing it as a duplicate. Rob provided the answer in a comment. If we re-open it, he can post his solution as an answer and others can learn from it. I voted to re-open this question.

Comment: @Rob can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line that says

```swift
button.addTarget(LoginController.self, action: #selector(presentRegistrationController), for: .touchUpInside)
```

But `LoginController.self` is not the target. The instance of this type should be the target. It should be:

```swift
private lazy var inviteRegistrationButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setAttributedTitle(withQuestion: "Don't have an account?", andAction: "Sign Up")
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentRegistrationController), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

Bottom line, the error message you shared with us was not actually saying “you should use `LoginController.self` in this context” but rather “hey, if you are using `self` here; in this context, that is equivalent to `LoginController.self`; is that really what you meant?” Needless to say, that is not what you meant. So we should not accept that suggested “fix”, but rather change the code so that `self` really refers to the instance (e.g., by making this a `lazy var` or by moving this `addTarget` call to the `addUISubviews` method).

The `inviteToLogInButton` has a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this question.